# How do I combine two successive rows if the second cell is empty in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe in python pandas:-

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       A       a1, a2, a3
2               a4, a5
3       B       b1, b2
4       C       c1, c2
5               c3, c4, c5, c6
6       D       d1
7               d2, d3
8       E       e1
9       F       f1, f2, f3
10      G       g1, g2, g3
                g4, g5
```

I want the expected output like this:-

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
1       A       a1, a2, a3, a4, a5
2       B       b1, b2
3       C       c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6
4       D       d1, d2, d3
5       E       e1
6       F       f1, f2, f3
7       G       g1, g2, g3, g4, g5
```

Wherever the cell under col2 is empty, let the row/cell under col3 be combined with cell above it.

Comment: what do you mean by empty? `None` or empty string or empty list?

Comment: pandas has function to fill places using value from above cell or below cell. and later you could use `groupby`

Answer (score 2):

You can do `ffill`

```
df.Col2 = df.Col2.mask(df.Col2).ffill()
out = df.groupby('Col2')['Col3'].agg(','.join).reset_index()
```

Comment: maybe worht adding a note to change `''` to `NaN` in case of empty strings

Comment: I got "TypeError: bad operand type for unary ~: 'str'" on both NaN and df.fillna('')